# Is $\Bbb Z / p$ where $p$ is not prime a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, finite-rings

Is it possible for a finite ring with unity in the form of $\Bbb Z / p$ where $p$ is not prime to be a PID?

Comment: If $p$ is not a prime, your ring is not even a domain.

Comment: It's 3 in the morning so I might be typing something incredibly stupid, but every ideal in Z mod n is principal (aren't they?) but Z mod n = jk is not a domain as j$\cdot$k = 0.  If p is prime then Z mod p is a domain it is a PID but if p is not prime then it simply can't be a domain and can't be a PID.  (Gad, I hope I didn't write something that's just plain wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is always a principal ideal *ring*, because it is a homomorphic image of the principal ideal ring $\mathbb Z$.

It is never a principal ideal *domain* when $n$ is composite, however, because a nontrivial factorization of $n$ leads directly to zero divisors in the ring.

Comment: Thank you. If p is prime then it's a field, and PID. But if p is composite then it's just a ring, not a domain. But if p is prime then Z mod p has no ideals even tho it's still PID. Is the criterion just if it had ideals then they would all be principal?

Comment: @danr.greenfield: Even a field has ideals, namely 
$\{0\}$ and the entire field. Since these are principal ideals -- namely $\langle 0\rangle$ and $\langle 1\rangle$ -- every field is a principal ideal ring. (And so a PID because a field is also a domain).